# Redmine 500 Internal Error on New Projects

Tags: apache-2.2, redmine

I am adding new projects to Redmine after transitioning it to a new server. The projects appear to add correctly. I can also add new CRs and DRs. However, after they are added, I can't actually browse to them. For example:

http://redmine.mysite.com/projects/myproject/issues

Gives me an Internal error. Same with the Calendar, Gantt charts and backlog. The issues are apparently added, though, because I can see a list of all issues by going to:

http://redmine.mysite.com/issues

What is interesting is that I can still select the old issues and they work. The issues added to new projects do not work.

When I check my logs (both Apache and Redmine logs) there is no apparent problems being reported. I'm really not sure where to go next from here. Any suggestions?

**Update for Apache Configuration**

It looks like this:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.9
PassengerRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName redmine.mysite.com
  ServerAdmin infrastructure@mysite.com
  DocumentRoot "/opt/redmine/latest/public"
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
  LogLevel WARN
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/redmine-error.log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/redmine-access.log" common

  <Directory /opt/redmine/latest/public>
    Options Indexes ExecCGI FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>

  <Location />
    Include conf.d/auth_kerb.inc
    Require ldap-attribute objectclass=person
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What does Apache configuration for `redmine.mysite.com` look like?

Comment: @quanta - Updated to answer your question.

Comment: Are you sure `redmine-error.log` has nothing relate to 500 error?

Comment: @quanta - Yeah. It's 0 bytes. Absolutely nothing in it. The only thing I have is in my Apache error log, I have: /opt/redmine/1.1.3/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:119:Warning: Gem::Dependency#version_requirements is deprecated and will be removed on or after August 2010.  Use #requirement

Comment: Turn `LogLevel` to `debug`, comment out `ErrorLog` in virtual host as a temporary to see if there is something in main Apache error log.

Comment: @quanta - Did that. There is no apparent issues. I do get a number of debug messages regarding Kerberos, but nothing alarming or out of place. (I do get some KeyErrors for Python. However, this still doesn't seem to be the problem.) Could it possibly have something to do with the database by chance?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1552/discussion-between-jascav-and-quanta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an installation issue and backlogs was not working. If I disable the backlogs module in the projects, everything works. I'll look into the deeper issue later, but the immediate need was met.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this ?

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```